# how to do re.compile() with a list in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings in which I want to filter for strings that contains keywords.

I want to do something like:

```
fruit = re.compile('apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pinepple', 'kiwi']
```

so I can then use re.search(fruit, list_of_strings) to get only the strings containing fruits, but I'm not sure how to use a list with re.compile. Any suggestions? (I'm not set on using re.compile, but I think regular expressions would be a good way to do this.)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to turn your fruit list into the string `apple|banana|peach|plum|pineapple|kiwi` so that it is a valid regex. The following should do this for you:

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pineapple', 'kiwi']
fruit = re.compile('|'.join(fruit_list))
```

As ridgerunner pointed out in comments, you will probably want to add word boundaries to the regex, otherwise the regex will match on words like `plump` since they have a fruit as a substring.

```
fruit = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(fruit_list))
```

Lastly, if the strings in `fruit_list` could contain special characters, you will probably want to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

```
'|'.join(map(re.escape, fruit_list))
```

Comment: +1 But I would add word boundaries like so: `fruit = re.compile('\\b(?:'+ '|'.join(fruit_list +')\\b'))`

Comment: @ridgerunner - Good point! In fact the way it is written now 'pineapple' in the string would always match 'apple', adding word boundaries to my answer.

Comment: Depending on what your list of strings is you may need tp escape them: fruit = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in fruit_list]))

Comment: Can you provide the same with Python 3.x

Comment: By using .search() is it possible to know which item was matched?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal It works in Python 3. Did you get an error or something?

Comment: @George For static strings like this, you can get [`.group(0)` from the resulting `Match` object](//docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group).

Answer (score 7):

As you want *exact* matches, no real need for regex imo...

```
fruits = ['apple', 'cherry']
sentences = ['green apple', 'yellow car', 'red cherry']
for s in sentences:
    if any(f in s for f in fruits):
        print s, 'contains a fruit!'
# green apple contains a fruit!
# red cherry contains a fruit!
```

---

EDIT: If you need access to the strings that matched:

```
from itertools import compress

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
s = 'green apple and red cherry'

list(compress(fruits, (f in s for f in fruits)))
# ['apple', 'cherry']
```

Comment: In this scenario, regex is more efficient than doing several separate substring tests.

Comment: @Andrew: depends on the number of fruits and sentences, and even so we are talking 2x in a matter of milliseconds.

Comment: @hop - I am pretty confident regex will be faster regardless of number of fruits or sentences.  With regex you also have access to the fruit that was matched.

Comment: @Andrew: Re efficiency: noted. Re access to matches: that's easy, check my update.

Comment: @Andrew: i will not dispute that regex are faster, but the non-regex solution might be sufficent on small data sets and easier to understand, especially if you have troubles with regex anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one regular expression, which will match, when any of the terms is found:

```
>>> s, t = "A kiwi, please.", "Strawberry anyone?"
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('apple|banana|peach|plum|pineapple|kiwi', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> pattern.search(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10046d4a8>
>>> pattern.search(t) # won't find anything
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
fruits =  ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pinepple', 'kiwi'] 
fruit_re = [re.compile(fruit) for fruit in fruits]
fruit_test = lambda x: any([pattern.search(x) for pattern in fruit_re])
```

Example usage:

```
fruits_veggies = ['this is an apple', 'this is a tomato']
return [fruit_test(str) for str in fruits_veggies]
```

**Edit**: I realized Andrew's solution is better. You could improve fruit_test with Andrew's regular expression as

```
fruit_test = lambda x: andrew_re.search(x) is None
```

Comment: Or if you need the strings: return [str for str in fruits_veggies if fruit_test(str)]

Answer (score 2):

Pyhton 3.x Update:

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pineapple', 'kiwi']
fruit = re.compile(r'\b(?:{0})\b'.format('|'.join(fruit_list))
```