# Fastest way to check does string contain any word from list

Tags: python, string, list, contain

I have Python application.

There is list of 450 prohibited phrases. There is message got from user. I want to check, does  this message contain any of this prohibited pharases. What is the fastest way to do that?

Currently I have this code:

```
message = "sometext"
lista = ["a","b","c"]

isContaining = false

for a, member in enumerate(lista):
 if message.contains(lista[a]):
  isContaining = true
  break
```

Is there any faster way to do that? I need to handle message (max 500 chars) in less than 1 second.

Comment: `isContaining = any(x in message for x in lista)`

Comment: First of all, remove the `enumerate` and `a,` part. Replace `lista[a]` with `member`. Second, is the `in` function not faster? So something like `if member in message:`

Comment: Membership testing is faster on [a `set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: I think you would be better to compile a regex and test the text on it

Comment: 1 second is a long time, does this really take longer?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I am not sure. Only telling you I should really low answer-time

Comment: @shevski: You think using a giant regex would be faster than using a set? Really?

Comment: @PM2Ring: you'd need a set that contains all possible substrings of message.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Good point. I guess you could have a set of all the significant words in the prohibited phrases, test the message to see if it has any of those significant words and only then do more thorough testing to see if it has the full prohibited phrases.

Comment: @PM2Ring: sounds like more work than testing whether it has any of the phrases. Anyway a compiled regex for this should blow any Python for loop out of the water.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Perhaps (I just modified my comment, BTW). I'm assuming that only a small percentage of the messages use prohibited words / phrases, so quickly eliminating thorough testing of each message ought to speed things up. I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function specially for that:

```
>>> message = "sometext"
>>> lista = ["a","b","c"]
>>> any(a in message for a in lista)
False
>>> lista = ["a","b","e"]
>>> any(a in message for a in lista)
True
```

---

Alternatively you could check the intersection of the sets:

```
>>> lista = ["a","b","c"]
>>> set(message) & set(lista)
set([])
>>> lista = ["a","b","e"]
>>> set(message) & set(lista)
set(['e'])
>>> set(['test','sentence'])&set(['this','is','my','sentence'])
set(['sentence'])
```

But you won't be able to check for subwords:

```
>>> set(['test','sentence'])&set(['this is my sentence'])
```

Comment: Also, sort the words in lista so that the smallest are first (I assume that those have the highest chance of occurring in the message)

Comment: set(message) isn't going to work if he's looking for words as opposed to characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using [regex compile from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750240/how-to-do-re-compile-with-a-list-in-python)

Consider memory and building time or expression, compile in advance.

```
lista = [...]
lista_escaped = [re.escape(item) for item in lista]
bad_match = re.compile('|'.join(lista_escaped))
is_bad = bad_match.search(message, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Combine with re.escape() for fixed string searches. re.compile will create a neatly optimized state machine for scanning strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the `any` builtin with the `in` operator:

```
isContaining = any(a in message for a in lista)
```

I don't know if this is the fastest way but it seems the simplest to me.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `set` `intersection` method

```
>>> message = "sometext"
>>> lista = ["a","b","c"]
>>> isContaining = False
>>> if set(list(message)).intersection(set(lista)):
...    isContaining = True
... 
>>> isContaining
False
>>> message = "sometext a"
>>> list(message)
['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', ' ', 'a']
>>> if set(list(message)).intersection(set(lista)):
...    isContaining = True
... 
>>> isContaining
True
```

Comment: yes, I need to create list of all combinations of the `message` string.