# Using Python to speed up string search using dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have developed some working code but it is extremely slow in its method.  I am trying to search a huge text file for 1000s of strings using my dictionary keys as the search strings.

Here's my working code...

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:  
        if filename.endswith('.txt'): 
            with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as f:
                print '\tProcessing file: '+filename


                for line in f:
                    if 'KEY_FRAME details' in line:
                        chunk = [next(f) for x in xrange(5)]
                        FRAME = chunk[5].split()
                        FRAME = FRAME[2]

                        framelist.append([FRAME])

            newdict = dict([(d[0], d[1:]) for d in framelist])

            f.close()

            with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if any(['FRAME = '+str(i) in line for i in newdict.keys()]):
                        ...do more text processing based on following lines and append to frame key...
```

The txt file is too large to read directly into memory, so I perform two searches on the same file, the first search is to collect frame numbers of interest based on a particular string header 'KEY_FRAME' and put the found frames into a list. I then convert this list into a dict using the frame numbers as keys and close the file.

I then re-open the file and perform a search for 'any' of the dict keys ('frame number') for each line in the file based on a new search string 'FRAME = '+str(Frame number).  But whilst the method works it is extremely slow.

I had thought of some sort of toggle of search strings during the initial file read, but some of the 'FRAME = '+str(Frame number) strings appear before the initial 'KEY_FRAME details' string in the file

Is there a more efficient method for the above (albeit rudimentary) code?

Thanks for reading.

After looking into a suggested regex solution, I have changed the end of my script to the following...

```
                        framelist.append(str(FRAME))


                f.seek(0)

                framed = re.compile('|'.join(framelist))
                framed = framed.pattern

                sentences = f
                for s in sentences:
                    if any(('FrameNumber = '+f) in s for f in framelist):
                        print 'first found'

                    if any(('FN = '+f) in s for f in framelist):
                        print 'second found'
```

The latest addition has seen some improvements in the processing speed (3 mins per log), so tolerable, though I was hoping for slightly better, but then I do have more than 6000 frame numbers to search for each time.

Comment: have you tried to use tuples instead of lists for the list comprehension bits?

Comment: Do I see it right that chunk has five elements and you want to split the sixth?

Comment: If you open a file with `with`, you do not need to close it explicitly.

Comment: Shouldn't you empty `framelist` for every file?

Comment: @MarcodeWit: Not emptying `framelist` will _certainly_ slow things down. OTOH, the OP may be accumulating details from the files that are being processed.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the feedback, unfortunately after I tried your suggestions with emptying framelist, initialising 'keys' outside the loop and replacing file open with f.seek(0) I still see slow progress of the script. Strange it's so slow though

Comment: @MikG: In that case, maybe you should try out the regex method mentioned in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do to improve the speed.

1) Don't close & re-open the file: you can rewind the file pointer to the start using `f.seek(0)`

2) You are rebuilding your list of strings for every line you check in the second `for line in f:` loop. You should do that outside the loop, eg

```
keys = ['FRAME = '+str(i) for i in newdict.keys()]
```

or even

```
keys = ['FRAME = '+i for i in newdict.keys()]
```

because it looks to me that the keys of `newdict` are already strings.

And then your test would become

```
if any(key in line for key in keys):
```

That test is using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, so `any()` can bail out as soon as it's found a match, which is generally *much* faster than building the whole list of matches before testing them.

Actually, you may be able to improve on this matching process by using regexes, as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27781638/4014959).

Comment: Hi @PM 2Ring, I manged to use your suggested method using your regex method...or at least I think I did what you suggested.  There seems to be a little improvement in the speed, it now only takes 4 mins to process each log file, however it's still a bit slower than I was hoping for.  I guess it's simply down to the large number of frame number I have to search through (+6000), so not sure if there is anything else possible to help with the speed.

Comment: @MikG: Maybe you should post your updated code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as code optimization questions are far more suitable there than they are here. You will need to post a fully working program (with some sample data) that others can run & test, but that doesn't mean you need to post your complete program. Just make a cut-down program that focuses on the code that needs optimizing.

Comment: Thanks for the mention about Code Review, I have posted there just now, so fingers crossed