# Matching strings with re.match doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750240/how-to-do-re-compile-with-a-list-in-python) link I used the following code:

```
my_other_string = 'the_boat_has_sunk'
my_list = ['car', 'boat', 'truck']
my_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(my_list))
if re.match(my_list, my_other_string):
    print('yay')
```

However it doesn't work. I tried printing my_list after re.compile and it prints this:

```
re.compile('\\b(?:car|boot|truck)\\b')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `re.search`. [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):
*If zero or more characters **at the beginning** of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.*

Comment: @stribizhev, it returns the same result.

Comment: Then please show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @stribizhev sorry I added the string to match

Comment: @user3605780 If the regex is matching the string with search, then what is the problem?

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: It does not because of `\b`. `_` is a *word* character. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a regular sentence where words are joined with an underscore. Since you are just checking if the word is present, you may either remove `\b` (as it is matching on a word boundary and `_` is a word character!) or add alternatives:

```
import re
my_other_string = 'the_boat_has_sunk'
my_list = ['car', 'boat', 'truck']
my_list = re.compile(r'(?:\b|_)(?:%s)(?=\b|_)' % '|'.join(my_list))
if re.search(my_list, my_other_string):
    print('yay')
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nR91vD)

**EDIT**:

Since you say *it has to be true if one of the words in the list is in the string, not only as a separate word*, but *it musn't match if for example boathouse is in the string*, I suggest first replacing non-word characters and `_` with space, and then using the regex you had with `\b`:

```
import re
my_other_string = 'the_boathouse_has_sunk'
my_list = ['car', 'boat', 'truck']
my_other_string = re.sub(r'[\W_]', ' ', my_other_string)
my_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(my_list))
if re.search(my_list, my_other_string):
    print('yay')
```

This will not print `yay`, but if you remove `house`, it will.

See [IDEONE Demo 2](http://ideone.com/UJsJ03)

Comment: I should've thought about it more clearly, because it musn't match if for example boathouse is in the string. So I need to remove all special characters. Am I correct that I have to split these with a | ? If so how do I remove a '|'?

Comment: I think in this case you need to replace with space all non-word characters with `re.sub(r'[\W_]', ' ', my_other_string)`, then apply the regex that you had with `\b`: `my_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(my_list))`.

Answer (score 7):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) only matches the beginning of the input string to the regular expression. So this would only work for string beginning with the strings from `my_list`.

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) on the other hand searches the entire string for a match to the regular expression.

```
import re

my_list = ['car', 'boat', 'truck']
my_other_string = 'I am on a boat'

my_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(my_list))
if re.search(my_list, my_other_string):#changed function call here
    print('yay')
```

For the string *"I am on a boat"*, `re.match` will fail because the beginning of the string is "I" which doesn't match the regular expression. `re.search` will also not match the first charecter but will instead go through the string until it gets to "boat", at which point it will have found a match.

If we instead use the string *"Boat is what I am on"*, `re.match` and `re.search` will both match the regular expression to the string because the string now starts with a match.