# Compare list with data with a list in a python dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, compression

I'm a graduate student and working wit python to prepare my data set for my research. I'm not that confident with the use of python, so I would really appreciate your Help.

Continuing on a previous asked question ([how to do re.compile() with a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750240/how-to-do-re-compile-with-a-list-in-python))

I would like to apply this kind of word recognition one column in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import compress

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":['green apple and red cherry', 'blue', 'apple, banana and cherry', 'banana banana split'],"b":[0,2,0,1]},
                  index = [1,2,3,4])

# Create a list to store the data
grades = []
grades = list(compress(fruits, (f in df.a for f in fruits)))
df['grades'] = pd.Series(grades)
```

This doesn't work out, since a data frame is generated where all 'grade-values' are NaN.

Additionally, I would like to know if this is also possible with a list of sentences, instead of a list of words. And how this could be done.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: df.grades should be ['apple, cherry', 'NAN', 'apple, banana, cherry', 'banana banana']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
df['grades'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in x.split(' ') if i in fruits))

# 1     apple, cherry
# 2                  
# 3    banana, cherry
# 4    banana, banana
# Name: grades, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Many thanks! Imagine that I would like to find fruits = ['green apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], then the script does not work anymore for the combination green apple. What do I have to change in the script to let it work out?

Comment: This is will be more expensive and logic will be completely different. You might want to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [422]: t = df.a.str.split(expand=True)

In [423]: df['grades'] = t[t.isin(fruits)].T.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep=', '))

In [424]: df
Out[424]:
                            a  b          grades
1  green apple and red cherry  0   apple, cherry
2                        blue  2
3    apple, banana and cherry  0  banana, cherry
4         banana banana split  1  banana, banana
```

Explanation:

```
In [425]: t
Out[425]:
        0       1      2       3       4
1   green   apple    and     red  cherry
2    blue    None   None    None    None
3  apple,  banana    and  cherry    None
4  banana  banana  split    None    None

In [426]: t.isin(fruits)
Out[426]:
       0      1      2      3      4
1  False   True  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False   True  False
4   True   True  False  False  False

In [427]: t[t.isin(fruits)]
Out[427]:
        0       1    2       3       4
1     NaN   apple  NaN     NaN  cherry
2     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN
3     NaN  banana  NaN  cherry     NaN
4  banana  banana  NaN     NaN     NaN
```